# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: expected single matching bean but found 3

Tags: java, spring

Como resolver ambiguedades en la CONEXION AUTOMATICA de Bean en Spring?
Imagenemos que tenemos una interfaz:

```
public interface Dessert {
    void eat();
}
```

Y tenemos tres Beans que implementan la interfaz:

BEAN CAKE:

```
@Component
public class Cake implements Dessert{
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a Cake !!!!");
    }
}
```

BEAN COOKIE:

```
@Component
public class Cookie implements Dessert{
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a Cookie !!!!");
    }
}
```

BEAN ICECREAM:

```
@Component
public class IceCream implements Dessert{
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a IceCream !!!!");
    }
}
```

Este seria el archivo de configuracion:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AutoBeanConfiguration {

}
```

Esta seria la clase Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AutoBeanConfiguration.class);
        Dessert dessert = ctxt.getBean(Dessert.class);
        dessert.eat();
        ctxt.close();

    }

}
```

El programa arroja la siguiente excepcion:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Dessert' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: cake,cookies,iceCream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1041)

Esto sucede porque tenemos tres Postres y Spring no sabe cual de ellos nos queremos comer.

Como podemos resolver la ambiguedad y decirle a spring cual de los Postres queremos que cree, para comernoslo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver la ambiguedad necesitas especificarle a spring cual va a ser tu concreta implementation en tu caso Cake, Cookie o IceCream.

Ejemplo

```
 Dessert dessert = ctx.getBean(Cookie.class);
 dessert.eat();
```

Esta serie de "problemas" se puede ver tambien cuando haces inyeccion de dependencias utlizando la anotacion @Autowired en casos donde posees una interface y multiples implementaciones.

Ejemplo

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {


    @Autowired
    Dessert dessert;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication app;
        app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
        // SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);


    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {

            dessert.eat();
        };
    }
}
```

De la misma manera que en tu ejemplo original nos mostraria el siguiente mensaje: **required a single bean, but 3 were found**, para corregir el problema bastaria con utilizar la anotacion @Primary encima del que bean que tiene la preferencia a ser inyectado o Utilizar la anotacion @Qualifier aunque este ultimo tiene una utilidad mas amplia.

```
@Component
@Primary
public class Cake implements Dessert {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a Cake !!!!");

    }
}
```